# display content differently within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

in my webpage I am using iframe to display some content and I am using this codes,

```
$(function() {
  if (window.self != window.top) {
    $(document.body).addClass("in-iframe");
   }
});
```

it's working fine but I am using multiple iframes, and I don't want to add "in-iframe" class in all iframes, is it possible to add "in-iframe" class in which iframe I want ? for example it will only work within this iframe `<iframe id="iframeID" src="#"></iframe>`, not in others.

Comment: So why isn't test for `window.top` not working for you? Should tell you if page is in iframe or not

Comment: it's working but I want to add that class only in which iframe I want ,

Comment: what does that mean? Please provide full explanation in words of what is not working. Add as update to the question

Comment: updated , Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add another condition to your code.

For example:

```
if ((window.self != window.top) && (window.frameElement.id=="iframeID")) {
    $(document.body).addClass("in-iframe");
}
```

Note that some conditions (like the above example) will only work if the iframe and the parent page are in the same domain.